# C/C++ irrlicht with Mac/xcode

Tags: c++, c, irrlicht

I have downloaded " Irrlicht SDK 1.7.2 " ' to use it on my mac, but when I click " Build and Run" and after it's done, it can't find the the app.

It says:

> CompileC
>   build/MacOSX.build/Debug/libIrrlicht.a.build/Objects-normal/i386/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.o
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm
>   normal i386 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2 cd
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
>   /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c++ -arch i386
>   -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -I/irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/build/MacOSX.build/Debug/libIrrlicht.a.build/Irrlicht.hmap
>   -F/irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/build/Debug -I/irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/build/Debug/include -I../../../include -I/irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/build/MacOSX.build/Debug/libIrrlicht.a.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -I/irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/build/MacOSX.build/Debug/libIrrlicht.a.build/DerivedSources
>   -DMACOSX -D_DEBUG -include /var/folders/w1/w1PRCRMnFk4CJv-F4-en5E+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MacOSX_Prefix-euovvscioydyedfabnweyxahsnjx/MacOSX_Prefix.pch
>   -c /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm
>   -o /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/build/MacOSX.build/Debug/libIrrlicht.a.build/Objects-normal/i386/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.o
>
> /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:
>   In member function 'bool irr::CIrrDeviceMacOSX::createWindow()':
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:575:
>   warning: 'CGDisplayBestModeForParameters' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDirectDisplay.h:487)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:575:
>   warning: 'CGDisplayBestModeForParameters' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDirectDisplay.h:487)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:578:
>   warning: 'CGDisplayCurrentMode' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDirectDisplay.h:507)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:578:
>   warning: 'CGDisplayCurrentMode' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDirectDisplay.h:507)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:582:
>   warning: 'CGDisplaySwitchToMode' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDirectDisplay.h:512)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:582:
>   warning: 'CGDisplaySwitchToMode' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDirectDisplay.h:512)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:614:
>   warning: 'CGLSetFullScreen' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/OpenGL.h:70)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:614:
>   warning: 'CGLSetFullScreen' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/OpenGL.h:70)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:
>   In member function 'virtual void
>   irr::CIrrDeviceMacOSX::setWindowCaption(const wchar_t*)':
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:888:
>   warning: 'stringWithCString:length:' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:385)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:
>   In member function 'void irr::CIrrDeviceMacOSX::setMouseLocation(int,
>   int)':
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:1050:
>   warning: 'CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval' is deprecated (declared
>   at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGRemoteOperation.h:373)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:1050:
>   warning: 'CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval' is deprecated (declared
>   at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGRemoteOperation.h:373)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:
>   In member function 'virtual irr::video::IVideoModeList*
>   irr::CIrrDeviceMacOSX::getVideoModeList()':
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:1452:
>   warning: 'CGDisplayAvailableModes' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDirectDisplay.h:481)
>   /irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/../MacOSX/CIrrDeviceMacOSX.mm:1452:
>   warning: 'CGDisplayAvailableModes' is deprecated (declared at
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDirectDisplay.h:481)
>
> Build Succeeded 26 warnings
>
> No launchable executable present at path.
>
> /Irrlicht SDK
>   1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/build/Debug/HelloWorld_dbg.app

I searched for the `HelloWorld_dbg.app`, but can't find it. I don't think it was created.

Comment: whats it? please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Next time when you post on multiple forums, make sure you don't copy nonsense from other sites (user name, post count, etc.) And properly format your question for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrlicht is not an *app*, it's a **library**. The SDK also contains a few tutorials and if you compile them, you will get some demo *apps*.

In Xcode, there are multiple targets to choose from. If you select `libIrrlicht.a`, only the library is built, so "build and *run*" doesn't make sense (there is nothing to *run*). If you compile the tutorials by selecting them one by one as targets, then "build and run" will start the selected app. But if you choose the target `All`, which I suppose you did, then the demo apps are built but you have to run them manually (out of Xcode) or tell Xcode which executable to run for the `All` target.

---

A word of warning, I doubt that the examples from the 1.7.2 SDK will run smoothly out of the box on your Mac, you will probably have to tweak them a little bit (to use the OpenGL device).